# Will the services rendered by a worker from an unorganized sector be counted in GDP?

Tags: gdp

My guess is it won't be because the unorganized sector isn't captured in GDP? but I read somewhere it will be. not sure if I am wrong or it was an error in the answer key.

please help

Comment: By the unorganized sector do you mean what Eurostat calls the informal economy - see [here](https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/statistics-explained/index.php?title=Building_the_System_of_National_Accounts_-_informal_sector/es#Definici.C3.B3n_del_sector_informal)?

Comment: Thank you, Adam. My sincere apologies for not clarifying before that I was talking in the context of the Indian economy. But thank you for this additional information. Have a great day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by ‘un-organized’ sector you mean gray and black market then these activities are not directly recorded in GDP. For example, if you pay 10e to a neighborhood kid to mow your lawn it won’t show on GDP as a spending. Although, you could say those activities still indirectly can increase GDP, as if then that kid goes and buys a lego at a store that would otherwise not be bought that purchase would raise GDP. But I don’t know what exactly you mean by unorganized if. If the spending/incomes in a sector are tracked by statistical office it will show up on GDP.

Comment: Thank you so much. your explanation lent me lot of clarity. Grateful for your insights.

Comment: Doesn't that depend on whether the lego was imported?

Comment: @aris it does as European I assume it’s not imported. Although now thinking about it even if it is imported it will be shown on national accounts just with negative sign